# Binding ComboBox with one Item define and one dynamic

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have ComboBox with one define ComboBoxItem and one with TextBox as template.
Something like this:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedItem="{Binding Repeatable}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="unbounded"/>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Repeatable, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBoxItem.Template>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

My problem is that i don't know ho to bind a Repeatable string property.
If Repeatable = unbounded, I've need select ConboBoxItem and, if other string need fill text property of TextBox.

On click of any item in ComboBox, the value must be shown as selected.

Don't know ho to do that. Thanks for answers and ideas.

Comment: You seem to be asking for DataTriggers. I think those will help you futher. Try them out: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/

Comment: Don't know how DataTriggers can help me. I need bind one property to a combobox of two items. If property value equels "unbounded" select comboItem "unbounded", if other then fill value in textbox in second ComboItem.

Comment: Maybe a Converter will help you. Bind those properties together and set a converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox Text="{Binding Repeatable}" IsEditable="True">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="unbounded"/>
</ComboBox>
```